# Custom links to create defect in an app with sdk 2.0

Tags: extjs, rally

I wrote an application which displays testCases in a treePanel. In that pannel, I have a specific column with icons for actions user can perform on a test case (show details, edit, add a bug...). In the column config, the renderer call this function, where `data` is an object with a `_ref` attribut like `/testcase/123456/` :

```js
_gridDataFormatTestCaseIcons:function(data)
{
    var IconsString = Ext.String.format('<a href="{0}" target="_blank"><span class="icon-testCase"></span></a>', Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(data));
    IconsString+= '&nbsp;';
    IconsString+= '<a href="#" onclick="Rally.nav.Manager.edit(\''+data._ref+'\')"><span class="icon-edit"></span></a>';
    IconsString+= '&nbsp;';
    IconsString+= '<a href="#" onclick="Rally.nav.Manager.create(\'defect\')"><span class="icon-defect"></span></a>';

    return IconsString ;
}
```

My first icon opens a new tab with details about the TestCase : OK. My 2nd icon opens a popup where I can edit my TestCase : OK. My third icon opens a popup where I can create a new bug. OK, but... I need to fill all the fileds, included the ones I guess it could be filled automatically.

So my question is about the third icon and the arguments of the function `Rally.nav.Manager.create('defect')` : the [SDK 2.0rc2 docs here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.nav.Manager-method-create) says it can take another argument `args` but don't give any details about it. Can i use it to specify the Owner and Test Case fields for example and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the args parameter can be an object that includes default attributes to populate into the Create Dialog. Only a limited subset of fields are accepted however:

```
Allowed args keys
User Story:
defaultName
rank
iteration
release
parent
dpyOid {dependency}

Defect:
defaultName
defectSuiteOid {Defect Suites}
testCaseResult
testCase
requirement
iteration

Defect Suite:
defaultName
rank
iteration

Portfolio Item:
defaultName
rank
parent

Task:
workProduct

Test Case:
testfolderOid {Test Folder}
artifactOid {Artifact}
```

It looks like the docs are a bit misleading, i.e., since we're creating a new object, instead of including a ref to an existing defect:

```
//Launch the create dialog
Rally.nav.Manager.create('/defect/12345');
```

The docs should read:

```
//Launch the create dialog
Rally.nav.Manager.create('defect');
```

Here's a quick example that pops and editor using a Button and sets the Defect Name and Default Iteration. Note that the Rally.nav.Manager functions generally only work when the app is installed and running inside Rally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    var myButtonContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'rallybutton',
                            text: 'Click Here to Create a New Defect',
                            handler: function() {
                                //Launch the create dialog
                                var defectDefaults = {
                                    defaultName: "My Defect",
                                    iteration: "12345678910"
                                };

                                Rally.nav.Manager.create('defect', defectDefaults);
                            }
                        }],
                    });
                    this.add(myButtonContainer);
                }
            });


            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
              name: 'Create Example'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this : `Rally.nav.Manager.create('defect',{testCase:'/testcase/12345',defaultName:'FooBar'})` where `/testcase/12345/` is valid : it's OK for defaultName, but not for testCase, which is one of the fields I need.
And, in your list of objects I can create, I don't see TestCaseResult. If I try `Rally.nav.Manager.create('testCaseResult');`, it opens me a popeup with the following message "The Test Case Result could not be saved because the Test Case has been deleted.". Maybe I need to pass one or more arguments that are not in the doc ?

Comment: I see what you mean. Now that you mention it, my iteration ref didn't populate in there either. I'll do some digging and let you know what I find.

Comment: For testCase creation, this line works : `Rally.nav.Manager.create('defect',{testCase:'12345',defaultName:'FooB‌​ar'})` : the string must be only objectID. Try the same in your example for iteration : `iteration: "12345678910"` instead of `iteration: "/iteration/12345678910"`...

Comment: Good find on the ObjectID's! Ultimately once Rally editable detail pages are released, you'll be able to pass an object's actual webservices JSON properties to the create page, and the defaults will populate in.